# Save/Load deque queue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am generating a memory buffer using collections.deque. Currently I am inserting values from left to right where every insertion consists on: a numpy array, a float value, another float valua and other numpy array.

The general form of my buffer is the following:

```
my_buffer = deque([numpy array, float, float, numpy array], [numpy array, float, float, numpy array])
```

What I want to do is to save the deque into my computer an then be able to load it as the same object. Currently I have tried to save it using numpy, using:

```
np.save(list(my_buffer))
```

However, I want to save the deque directly. Is there any way to save this kind of buffer into my disk memory and then load it?

Comment: get items from deque, convert to  list or numpy array and save it - using json or numpy's functions for array. Eventually you can try to save it directly using `pickle`

Comment: What is `array`?

Comment: @furas: Thanks, currently I am doing that like np.array(list(my_buffer)) and then np.save.  However I'm not sure if I can load the numpy array and then get back a deque.

Comment: @ghchoi Sorry, I copied a print of my buffer. It is a np.ndarray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pickle.dump(my_buffer, open('buffer.pkl', 'wb'))

my_buffer_2 = pickle.load(open('buffer.pkl', 'rb'))
```

I do not know what your `array` is, however, it works for me with my `array` instance.

```
class array:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l
```